# Set color for all UINavigationBars

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I have an app with multiple UINavigationControllers. Now I want to set their background color to the same color. I wrote this into the application method of AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

The same statement for UITabBars works:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

What is my mistake?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gotta be `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.darkGray`.